# Jquery each loop not able to acces object by variable

Tags: jquery, loops, variables, object, each

I've got an object that looks like

```
var countryRegions = 
    {
        "config": {
            "show_all_regions": true,
            "regions_required": ["AT", "CA", "EE", "FI", "FR", "DE", "HK", "LV", "LT", "RO", "ES", "CH", "US"]
        },
        "HK": {
            "494": {
                "code": "FN",
                "name": "Hong Kong"
            }
        },
        "CH": {
            "104": {
                "code": "AG",
                "name": "Aargau"
            },
            "106": {
                "code": "AR",
                "name": "Appenzell Ausserrhoden"
            },
            "105": {
                "code": "AI",
                "name": "Appenzell Innerrhoden"
            },
            "108": {
                "code": "BL",
                "name": "Basel-Landschaft"
            },
            "109": {
                "code": "BS",
                "name": "Basel-Stadt"
            },
            "107": {
                "code": "BE",
                "name": "Bern"
            },
            "110": {
                "code": "FR",
                "name": "Freiburg"
            },
            "111": {
                "code": "GE",
                "name": "Genf"
            },
            "112": {
                "code": "GL",
                "name": "Glarus"
            },
            "113": {
                "code": "GR",
                "name": "Graub\u00fcnden"
            },
            "114": {
                "code": "JU",
                "name": "Jura"
            },
            "115": {
                "code": "LU",
                "name": "Luzern"
            },
            "116": {
                "code": "NE",
                "name": "Neuenburg"
            },
            "117": {
                "code": "NW",
                "name": "Nidwalden"
            },
            "118": {
                "code": "OW",
                "name": "Obwalden"
            },
            "120": {
                "code": "SH",
                "name": "Schaffhausen"
            },
            "122": {
                "code": "SZ",
                "name": "Schwyz"
            },
            "121": {
                "code": "SO",
                "name": "Solothurn"
            },
            "119": {
                "code": "SG",
                "name": "St. Gallen"
            },
            "124": {
                "code": "TI",
                "name": "Tessin"
            },
            "123": {
                "code": "TG",
                "name": "Thurgau"
            },
            "125": {
                "code": "UR",
                "name": "Uri"
            },
            "126": {
                "code": "VD",
                "name": "Waadt"
            },
            "127": {
                "code": "VS",
                "name": "Wallis"
            },
            "128": {
                "code": "ZG",
                "name": "Zug"
            },
            "129": {
                "code": "ZH",
                "name": "Z\u00fcrich"
            }
        },
        "US": {
            "1": {
                "code": "AL",
                "name": "Alabama"
            },
            "2": {
                "code": "AK",
                "name": "Alaska"
            },
            "3": {
                "code": "AS",
                "name": "American Samoa"
            },
            "4": {
                "code": "AZ",
                "name": "Arizona"
            },
            "5": {
                "code": "AR",
                "name": "Arkansas"
            },
            "6": {
                "code": "AE",
                "name": "Armed Forces Africa"
            },
            "7": {
                "code": "AA",
                "name": "Armed Forces Americas"
            },
            "8": {
                "code": "AE",
                "name": "Armed Forces Canada"
            },
            "9": {
                "code": "AE",
                "name": "Armed Forces Europe"
            },
            "10": {
                "code": "AE",
                "name": "Armed Forces Middle East"
            },
            "11": {
                "code": "AP",
                "name": "Armed Forces Pacific"
            },
            "12": {
                "code": "CA",
                "name": "California"
            },
            "13": {
                "code": "CO",
                "name": "Colorado"
            },
            "14": {
                "code": "CT",
                "name": "Connecticut"
            },
            "15": {
                "code": "DE",
                "name": "Delaware"
            },
            "16": {
                "code": "DC",
                "name": "District of Columbia"
            },
            "17": {
                "code": "FM",
                "name": "Federated States Of Micronesia"
            },
            "18": {
                "code": "FL",
                "name": "Florida"
            },
            "19": {
                "code": "GA",
                "name": "Georgia"
            },
            "20": {
                "code": "GU",
                "name": "Guam"
            },
            "21": {
                "code": "HI",
                "name": "Hawaii"
            },
            "22": {
                "code": "ID",
                "name": "Idaho"
            },
            "23": {
                "code": "IL",
                "name": "Illinois"
            },
            "24": {
                "code": "IN",
                "name": "Indiana"
            },
            "25": {
                "code": "IA",
                "name": "Iowa"
            },
            "26": {
                "code": "KS",
                "name": "Kansas"
            },
            "27": {
                "code": "KY",
                "name": "Kentucky"
            },
            "28": {
                "code": "LA",
                "name": "Louisiana"
            },
            "29": {
                "code": "ME",
                "name": "Maine"
            },
            "30": {
                "code": "MH",
                "name": "Marshall Islands"
            },
            "31": {
                "code": "MD",
                "name": "Maryland"
            },
            "32": {
                "code": "MA",
                "name": "Massachusetts"
            },
            "33": {
                "code": "MI",
                "name": "Michigan"
            },
            "34": {
                "code": "MN",
                "name": "Minnesota"
            },
            "35": {
                "code": "MS",
                "name": "Mississippi"
            },
            "36": {
                "code": "MO",
                "name": "Missouri"
            },
            "37": {
                "code": "MT",
                "name": "Montana"
            },
            "38": {
                "code": "NE",
                "name": "Nebraska"
            },
            "39": {
                "code": "NV",
                "name": "Nevada"
            },
            "40": {
                "code": "NH",
                "name": "New Hampshire"
            },
            "41": {
                "code": "NJ",
                "name": "New Jersey"
            },
            "42": {
                "code": "NM",
                "name": "New Mexico"
            },
            "43": {
                "code": "NY",
                "name": "New York"
            },
            "44": {
                "code": "NC",
                "name": "North Carolina"
            },
            "45": {
                "code": "ND",
                "name": "North Dakota"
            },
            "46": {
                "code": "MP",
                "name": "Northern Mariana Islands"
            },
            "47": {
                "code": "OH",
                "name": "Ohio"
            },
            "48": {
                "code": "OK",
                "name": "Oklahoma"
            },
            "49": {
                "code": "OR",
                "name": "Oregon"
            },
            "50": {
                "code": "PW",
                "name": "Palau"
            },
            "51": {
                "code": "PA",
                "name": "Pennsylvania"
            },
            "52": {
                "code": "PR",
                "name": "Puerto Rico"
            },
            "53": {
                "code": "RI",
                "name": "Rhode Island"
            },
            "54": {
                "code": "SC",
                "name": "South Carolina"
            },
            "55": {
                "code": "SD",
                "name": "South Dakota"
            },
            "56": {
                "code": "TN",
                "name": "Tennessee"
            },
            "57": {
                "code": "TX",
                "name": "Texas"
            },
            "58": {
                "code": "UT",
                "name": "Utah"
            },
            "59": {
                "code": "VT",
                "name": "Vermont"
            },
            "60": {
                "code": "VI",
                "name": "Virgin Islands"
            },
            "61": {
                "code": "VA",
                "name": "Virginia"
            },
            "62": {
                "code": "WA",
                "name": "Washington"
            },
            "63": {
                "code": "WV",
                "name": "West Virginia"
            },
            "64": {
                "code": "WI",
                "name": "Wisconsin"
            },
            "65": {
                "code": "WY",
                "name": "Wyoming"
            }
        },
        "CA": {
            "66": {
                "code": "AB",
                "name": "Alberta"
            },
            "67": {
                "code": "BC",
                "name": "British Columbia"
            },
            "68": {
                "code": "MB",
                "name": "Manitoba"
            },
            "70": {
                "code": "NB",
                "name": "New Brunswick"
            },
            "69": {
                "code": "NL",
                "name": "Newfoundland and Labrador"
            },
            "72": {
                "code": "NT",
                "name": "Northwest Territories"
            },
            "71": {
                "code": "NS",
                "name": "Nova Scotia"
            },
            "73": {
                "code": "NU",
                "name": "Nunavut"
            },
            "74": {
                "code": "ON",
                "name": "Ontario"
            },
            "75": {
                "code": "PE",
                "name": "Prince Edward Island"
            },
            "76": {
                "code": "QC",
                "name": "Quebec"
            },
            "77": {
                "code": "SK",
                "name": "Saskatchewan"
            },
            "78": {
                "code": "YT",
                "name": "Yukon Territory"
            }
        },
        "AT": {
            "102": {
                "code": "BL",
                "name": "Burgenland"
            },
            "99": {
                "code": "KN",
                "name": "K\u00e4rnten"
            },
            "96": {
                "code": "NO",
                "name": "Nieder\u00f6sterreich"
            },
            "97": {
                "code": "OO",
                "name": "Ober\u00f6sterreich"
            },
            "98": {
                "code": "SB",
                "name": "Salzburg"
            },
            "100": {
                "code": "ST",
                "name": "Steiermark"
            },
            "101": {
                "code": "TI",
                "name": "Tirol"
            },
            "103": {
                "code": "VB",
                "name": "Vorarlberg"
            },
            "95": {
                "code": "WI",
                "name": "Wien"
            }
        }
    }
```

I've got a select list that looks like:

```
<select id="billing:region_id">
    <option value="1"> Alabama </option>
    <option value="2"> Arizona </option>
    etc....
</select>
```

Im trying to loop through the option elements and append their corresponding country code as an id on the element however it is coming back as undefined when I loop like such:

```
jQuery("#billing\\:region_id option").each(function(k,v){

            v.id = countryRegions['US'][Number(v.value)]['code'];

});
```

and none of these work

```
 v.id = countryRegions['US'][Number(v.value)]['code'];
 v.id = countryRegions['US'][Number(v.value)].code;
 v.id = countryRegions.US[Number(v.value)]['code'];
```

but when I say

```
 v.id = countryRegions['US'][1]['code'];
```

this works just fine but each option element gets the first object code as would be expected.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't think it should matter, but why are you converting `v.value` to a number, when the keys in the object are strings?

Comment: You have a mistake in the selector. `#billing\\:region_id` should be `#billing\\:region`

Comment: When I correct that, your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/d2dbs39q/1/

Comment: Sorry that was a typeo the id of the select is billing:region_id ive updated the question. Im making sure the value is a int not string as the key is parsed as an int. Strange though that your code works on fiddle and not on mine. I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined

Comment: Maybe you have values in your `select` that don't have matching elements in the array.

Comment: What is `v.value` when you get that error?

Comment: OMG I must have had a long day. YES the first element in the array was the default "Select and option" with a null value.  Adding a simple if statment before trying to bind the object to the element made this work. Thanks for the help it probably would have taken me another hour to realize this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check that the value exists in the array before trying to use it.

```
jQuery("#billing\\:region_id option").each(function(k,v){
    if (countryRegion.US[v.value]) {
        v.id = countryRegion.US[v.value].code;
    }
});
```